# What does Perl return when a numeric comparison is false?

Tags: perl

I am trying to execute this code. What puzzles me is why doesn't this comparison return any value when false. Is this the default behavior of these comparison operators?

```
my $output = (2 <= 1); 
print "value=$output";
```

Will a comparison operator return `undef` when its logical check fails?

Comment: You may find Contextual::Return to be useful and relevant to look at. It detects operation context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [relational operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Relational-Operators)

> return 1 for true and a special version of the defined empty string, "" , which counts as a zero but is exempt from warnings about improper numeric conversions, just as "0 but true" is.

The value you get back is actually a dualvar. It has separate numeric and string values (not a special version of the empty string, really). The numeric value is 0 and the string value is the empty string. You used the string portion, which is empty, but the 0 is still there. You can look inside the variable records with [Devel::Peek](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Devel::Peek):

```
use Devel::Peek;
my $result = ( 1 == 2 );
Dump( $result );
```

In the SV (scalar value) thing behind the scenes, you see the string value in the PV  and the numeric value in the IV And NV (the integer and numeric values):

```
SV = PVNV(0x7fe602802750) at 0x7fe603002e70
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,IOK,NOK,POK,pIOK,pNOK,pPOK)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x7fe6026016b0 ""\0
  CUR = 0
  LEN = 16
```

There are other sorts of dualvars too. The `$!` error variable has the error number and the error text, for instance (and I talk about that in [Mastering Perl](http://www.masteringperl.org)). This isn't something you normally have to worry about because Perl does the right thing for the context.

If you always want a numeric value, use it in a numeric context:

```
my $numeric = 0 + $result;   # 0
```

You can create your own dualvars with [Scalar::Util](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Scalar::Util)'s `dualvar`, and you can check if a scalar is a dualvar with `isdual`.

```
use Scalar::Util qw(isdual);
my $result = ( 1 == 2 );
print isdual($result) ? "dualvar" : "Not dualvar";
```

If you wanted to check that the value you got back was defined (you said it wasn't), you can check with [defined](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html). An empty string is defined, though. If you want to check that it's not the empty string, you can use [length](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html). These help when the value you have isn't printable.

Comment: So dualvar nature prevents warning in numeric context?

Comment: Worth mentioning: if you want your own functions to return these special true and false values you can return `!!1` (true) or `!!0` (false).

Comment: @mpapec: There's no warning in numeric context because it's not an uninitialized numeric value.

Comment: @tobyink That doesn't work for `!!( 2==1 )` though. You still get the empty string. That's why I used `0 + $result`.

Comment: @briandfoy - yes, you do get the empty string, which is why I said **"if you want your own functions to return these special true and false values"** and why I didn't say "if you want your own functions to return a number".

Comment: @briandfoy Is there any specific reason for setting perl behavior this way. Wouldn't it have been better if numeric comparison just returns 1 for true and 0 for false :)

Comment: @chidori - Perl has scalars. They are just single values. By design, Perl uses that single value in the way the operator wants to handle it. Numeric operators want numbers, so Perl has a way to turn strings into numbers without disturbing the string representation. It's the stuff we talk about at the beginning of Learning Perl.

Answer (score 3):

Boolean operators return 1 on true and '' on false. You are trying to print the empty string.

Try this for a test

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $output = (2 <= 1); 
print $output ? "value=|$output|" : "value=<$output>";
```

Comment: `$output` is always defined and never `undef`

Comment: Actually, Perl's false value is a special empty string that doesn't produce a warning when used in numeric context.  (A normal empty string generates an "Argument isn't numeric" warning if used where a number is expected.)

Comment: This isn't really true. And, Perl isn't using an empty string in numeric context.

Comment: @briandfoy it is interesting to note that Data::Dump(er) and json prefer string over numeric representation; `perl -MJSON -e 'print encode_json([ 1==2 ])'`

Comment: Well, JSON and Data::Dumper stringify data structures, so that's not too surprising :)

Comment: @mpapec The original question wanted to know if the return value from the test was undef(). The original version of my code was to show that it wasn't

Answer (score 1):

Comparisons can return a special false value that is an empty string or 0 depending on the context in which it is evaluated. If you are looking for specific values for true and false it is much safer to use a statement like this:

```
my $output = ( 2 <= 1 ) ? 1 : 0;
```

The following code will illustrate the behaviour of the special false value.

```
use 5.014; 
say ( 2 <= 1); # prints nothing
my $output = ( 2 <= 1 ) ? 1 : 0; 
say $output; # prints 0
$output = ( 2 > 1 ) ? 1 : 0 ; 
say int $output; # prints 1
say $output; # prints 1
$output = ( 2 <= 1 ) ; 
say int $output ; # prints 0
```

If you're unfamiliar with the ? : construct see: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Conditional-Operator

Comment: The `int` turns all non-numerics into 0, and sets the IV and NV portions to create a dualvar. :)

Comment: @briandfoy: not sure what case you are addressing in that comment; int normally sets either IV/UV or NV, not both

Comment: I'm saying that `int` doesn't do anything special for the result of a numeric comparison. Give it 'abc' and it will return 0, but also preserve 'abc'.

Comment: good point about int. I was just looking for a quick demonstration that the false value evaluated numerically as 0.

Answer (score -1):

That expression returns an empty string (`""`), which Perl considers as a false value in evaluating sentences like `if` or `unless`.

In Perl, `0`, `"0"` and an empty string (`""`) are false. `undef` is also false, but you may get a warning. Anything else is true.