# perl false values are not printed

Tags: perl

when I print false values in perl I get nothing printed. Probably this is a very simple question, but I searched google without finding an answer.

Code:

```
print "2 == 2 :", 2 == 2, "\n";
print "2 != 2 :", 2 != 2, "\n";
print "2 == 3 :", 2 == 3, "\n";
print "2 != 3 :", 2 != 3", "\n";
```

This is the output:

```
2 == 2:1
2 != 2 :
2 == 3 :
2 != 3 :1
```

why the false value is not being printed?

Comment: read: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26894436/632407

Comment: You can convert a false value to a zero if you want to do that: `perl -E 'say 2!=2 ? 1 : 0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl doesn't have a strict boolean type - it has a bunch of things that evaluate as 'false' and everything else is true.

Now, here's the thing - false is anything that's numerically zero, or an empty string.  Or indeed `undef`.

So:

```
print "Zero" if 0; 
print "Empty" if ''; 
print "Undef" if undef;
```

None will print, because all the conditionals are 'false'.

Now, when you try and create a 'boolean' how should perl know what value to give it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $value = !1;
my $othervalue = !'true';
```

What is `$value` or `$othervalue` at this point? I mean, any of `0`, `0.00`, `''` (and a few others) would be 'valid'.  But here's the thing - it doesn't matter, because it's a boolean. As long as when you feed it into `if` it does the right thing, then perl can return whatever it likes.

Perl cheats - it returns from this operation a [`dualvar`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#dualvar) - a variable with two values, one for uses in a string context, and the other for use in a numeric context.

You can do a thing that doesn't work otherwise:

```
use Scalar::Util qw ( isdual dualvar );
print "\$value is dual\n" if isdual $value;
print "Coercing numerically:", 0+$value,"\n"; 
print "Coercing stringifically:", ''.$value,"\n";
```

This won't work for normal numerical (or string) values. You can recreate the same with the `dualvar` function:

```
my $special = dualvar ( 666, "the beast" );
```

Meddling with dualvars isn't generally good practice though. Just print explicitly what you want, with a conditional test and you've got no ambiguity there.

Answer (score 0):

The 'false' value has been printed, sort off, don't worry about it.

Perl has a very simple concept of 'false', see [the Perl Documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood) for more details. The link provided by @jm666 tells more about it. Basically, `0` or `""` or `undef` are all three 'false'.

Your `print` happened to 'stringify' the special 'false' value, which is the empty string.

Comment: There is no stringification going on here.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't expect to be able to print Boolean values. All that you should expect to be able to do with Boolean values is to ask them if they are true or false.

As it happens, you often **can** print Perl's Boolean values and get a useful result. Most Perl Boolean operations will give you 1 for true and an empty string for false. [**Update:** Strictly speaking, what you're getting is a [dualvar](https://metacpan.org/pod/Scalar::Util#dualvar) with the values '' and 0.] That's what you're seeing here. The false value *is* being printed, but it's an empty string.

If you want to see something specific to indicate your false value, then you need to implement that yourself.

```
print "2 == 3 :", (2 == 3 ? 'true' : 'false'), "\n";
```

But really, Boolean values aren't intended for displaying.

Comment: Actually a `false` test is giving back a `dualvar ( 0, '' )` you can do addition to a `false` value, which you couldn't with a pure empty string.

Comment: @Sobrique: Yes. I was simplifying :-)